# Flashing power led

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

The power LED on my HP Pavilion is permanently blinking, even when on mains.  It also battles to 'awake' from Standby mode, just powering up without restoring.  It also does this when I try and power up without mains.

I seem to recall an esoteric procedure to do this and that while pressing this or that, but it eludes me.  Kudos to the person that can diagnose the problem and or remind me of the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flashing power LED usually indicates power-supply problems.
Here is one reference discussion: [HP pavilion t490 power light flashing - won't start](http://www.techsupportforum.com/hardware-support/motherboards-bios-cpu/177357-hp-pavilion-t490-power-light-flashing-wont-start.html)

Answer (score 0):

The referance in answer 1 leads to a basic notion that reseting the power supply and applying only the mainboard power will fix this issue. The chances are a hot connection to your main board could cause more problems than you already have. My work around is a power supply tester. One you can check the all of yoru power supply connector with. First turn off the power supply and unplug all the power connections from your board and devices. Second connect the main and four pin connectors to the power supply tester and turn on the power supply. If all the lights come on that are supposed to come on then the power supply is ok. Turn off your power supply, remove the tester and reinstall the main and four pin connectors on the board. Power up your system, if you can get to a bios screen then you're half the way there. Turn off the power supply and connect one device at a time, not the HDD yet, until you can boot to the bios screen with everything except the HDD connected. I have had devices like a DVD/CD drives stop the boot process because it had gone bad, you cann't find it if you reconnect everything at once. The last step is reconnecting the HDD. If everthing goes well it should boot-up. If you didn't suspect any problems with you devices and your power supply is ok then you can just reconnect everything and power-up the system.

Comment: Please try to format your post a bit better. Walls of text are hard to read.